# Create Excel Formula to extract all numbers in ri after string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Create a formula that returns only the characters that appear after "X" for the given character strings. The same formula must work for the whole column!

Example of how it should look like after you apply your formula:

```
765892X329  329
752238X44   44
```

Comment: See [ask] a question with a [mcve]. You currently asked **no** question at all. This is a kind reminder this is not a free-coding website. Show your *own* effort at solving your *own* problem. Sidenote: This very much looks like homework to me.

Answer (score 2):

### FIND / SEARCH

1. Find the position of the "X":

   ```
   =FIND("X",A1)
   ```

   An error will occur if there is no "X".
2. Get the right characters after the "X":

   ```
   =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("X",A1))
   ```
3. Handle the error:

   ```
   =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("X",A1)),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("X",A1)),"")
   ```
4. Allow a lower case "x":

   ```
   =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",A1)),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("X",A1)),"")
   ```
5. Convert the resulting text into a number:

   ```
   =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",A1)),VALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("X",A1))),"")
   ```

   An error will occur if the resulting text is not 'numeric'.
6. Handle errors differently:

   ```
   =IFERROR(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("X",A1))),"")
   ```
7. Abandon the 'convert to number' idea:

   ```
   =IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("X",A1)),"")
   ```
8. Abandon the 'allow lower case' idea.

   ```
   =IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("X",A1)),"")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If the range is in Column A and you have office 365 you can use the following:
`=MID(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),FIND("X",FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""))+1,LEN(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")))`

Else use:
`=MID(A:A,FIND("X",A:A)+1,LEN(A:A))` and drag down.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
=RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("X",A3,1))*1
```

Assumed is that the first item is in cell A3, then drag down. The *1 is to convert from text to number.